# Nginx serves images but not css for django app

Tags: django, deployment, nginx-config

I use Django/Gunicorn/Nginx stack for my small webapp. I managed to put the app to production  except that my app shows static images correctly but does not find the css file.

My static resources like images, css, js were collected by `python manage.py collectstatic` outside of the project folder, to a folder accessible by Nginx: `/var/www/example.com/html/static/`. The content of the folder:
`

```
├── admin
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── autocomplete.css
│   │   ├── ....
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── calendar-icons.svg
│   │   ├── ....
│   └── js
│       ├── SelectBox.js
│       ├── ....
├── booking
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── andromeda.webp
│   │   ├── ....
├── img
│   └── favicon_16.ico
└── ksa .....
```

`

My index page refers to images and css in the booking app. Here are two examples:

```html
<!--It is located in the head section-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'booking/css/style.css' %}">

<!--It is located in the body section-->
<img src="{% static 'booking/img/andromeda.webp' %}" alt="">
```

As you can see the references are following the same structure and consistent with the real folder structure. That's why it is weird that images return 200 status code while css returns 404. When I check the generated html, it also seems good. The generated html snippets:

```html
<!--It is located in the head section-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/booking/css/style.css">

<!--It is located in the body section-->
<img src="/static/booking/img/andromeda.webp" alt="">
```

Here is my relevant part of my django setting file:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv()

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['example.com', 'www.example.com','localhost']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'booking.apps.BookingConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]

SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE=True

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ksa.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ksa.wsgi.application'

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/html/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/html/uploads/'
```

Finally, here is my Nginx settings:

```ini
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/html/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/html/uploads/;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    
    #No browser side cache for html and css
    location ~* \.(?:html|css){
    expires -1;
    }

    #1 week browser side cache for images
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|webp){
    expires 1w;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location /404.html {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        internal;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

So, do you have any idea, how can it happen that css is not found although it is referred exactly the same way as the images?

UPDATE:
Checking the access log, none of the static resources are accessible:

```
65.154.226.169 - - [13/Feb/2024:07:42:45 +0100] "GET /static/booking/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.5938.132 Safari/537.36"

65.154.226.169 - - [13/Feb/2024:07:42:45 +0100] "GET /static/booking/img/fokep.webp HTTP/1.1" 404 197 "https://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.5938.132 Safari/537.36"
```

The **error log of Nginx** shows more interesting fact:

```
2024/02/13 07:42:45 [error] 508095#508095: *3407 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/booking/css/style.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 65.154.226.169, server: example.com, request: "GET /static/booking/css/style.css HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"

2024/02/13 07:42:45 [error] 508095#508095: *3410 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/static/booking/img/andromeda.webp" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 65.154.226.169, server: example.com, request: "GET /static/booking/img/andromeda.webp HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

So, now it is trivial why static resources are not served. Still I do not understand from where Nginx takes this path, if the configuration file for Nginx includes:

```
location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/example.com/html/static/;
    }
```

No any reference on `/usr/share/nginx/html/static/`

Comment: Try opening `andromeda.webp` with `?whatever` parameter in URL. Perhaps all static files handling is broken, you're looking at cached for `1w` image. And try investigating nginx error log to see specific error message with additional details.

Comment: I agree with Ivan's advice and want to add: Do you somewhere include the mime types in your nginx conf? I think some browsers do not show the css without proper mime types.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: https://example.com/static/booking/img/andromeda.webp is not accessible, so you are right it comes from the cache. Still, I do not know how it went to the cache if it is always 404.

Comment: @Tarquinius the nginx.conf includes a row : include /etc/nginx/mimetypes; I checked also what is inside of that file and all the css and picture format definitions are fine. So definetely something is wrong with my static mapping. I removed now my cache from nginx during the development to see results of any modifications. My problem is still thatm seemingly the mapping should be fine.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I double checked it. Switched off the cache, restarted nginx, started an incognito browser and I could reach without any problem the `https://example.com/static/booking/img/andromeda.webp`, but I can not access `https://example.com/static/booking/css/style.css` from the url bar.

Comment: Perhaps there is some other nginx config or instance which takes precedence and your config is not used. Seems to be nginx-only related question, try narrowing your question to nginx configuration problem and ask without django code and tag - more experienced in nginx will look into it. Be sure to copy errors from nginx error log to new question. Searching for `/usr/share/nginx/html` can find similar questions on SO and serverfault.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Very good hint. Actually, it turned out that if none of the uri matches in my Nginx conf file, Nginx fallbacks to /usr/share/nginx folder, so that's why I see it in the error log despite I did not specified it.

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash as starting char for the strings `MEDIA_URL` and [`STATIC_URL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#static-url).

```py
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/html/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  # old 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'  # old 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/html/uploads/'
```

Without the leading slash your path or source (`src=""`) is relative, meaning it refers to the current url you are on right now.
When you open [www.domain.com/books/authors/](http://www.domain.com/books/authors/) and have

```html
<img src="{% static 'images/myimage.png' %}" alt="My Image">
```

Then the url would resolve to [www.domain.com/books/authors/static/images/myimage.png](http://www.domain.com/books/authors/static/images/myimage.png)

But your nginx conf is configured in a way that you want absolute paths and not relative paths.

What's weird to me is that you did not report issues with the media files. What's also weird, that the total paths that you show do indeed have a leading slash like so:

```html
<!--It is located in the body section-->
<img src="/static/booking/img/andromeda.webp" alt="">
```

Here, according to your stated `STATIC_URL` settings, should be no leading slash... Confusing.

If this does not work make sure to always run `collectstatic` **after** making changes to `STATIC_ROOT`. Always reload the nginx conf after making changes to it (obvious I guess).

If the error still persists I would like to see the nginx error log files.

Answer (score 0):

I applied a brute force approach to find the solution. I tried all the potential combination for the nginx config file and the django settings.py file.

It was the working combination:
Relevant snippet from settings.py:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/html/static/'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/example.com/html/uploads/'
```

Relevant snippet from the webs server configuration file

```
server {
    ...
    
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/example.com/html/static;
    }
    
    location /media {
        alias /var/www/example.com/html/uploads;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
...
```